# how to avoid store data in local database in cloudant

Tags: android, database, couchdb, cloudant

right now when i insert data to cloudant server then it store in local database and cloudant server. but i want it store only at cloudant server not in local database in android.

my library is

```
compile 'com.cloudant:cloudant-sync-datastore-android:1.1.4'
```

insert code is

```
 public Map<String, String> createDocument(Map<String, String> map) {
        DocumentRevision rev = new DocumentRevision();
        rev.setBody(DocumentBodyFactory.create(map));
        try {
            DocumentRevision created = sunDatastore.createDocumentFromRevision(rev);
            return map;
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

call back funcation is

```
public List<BasicDocumentMAP> allTasks() {
        int nDocs = this.sunDatastore.getDocumentCount();
        List<DocumentRevision> all = this.sunDatastore.getAllDocuments(0, nDocs, true);
        List<BasicDocumentMAP> arrayListBasicDocumentMAP = new ArrayList<>();

        // Filter all documents down to those of type Task.
        for (DocumentRevision rev : all) {
            BasicDocumentMAP basicDocumentMAP = new BasicDocumentMAP();
            basicDocumentMAP.setBasicDocumentRevision(rev);
            basicDocumentMAP.setMap(rev.asMap());
            arrayListBasicDocumentMAP.add(basicDocumentMAP);
        }
        if (arrayListBasicDocumentMAP != null)
            return arrayListBasicDocumentMAP;
        else
            return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Please help me and thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you are using is a "sync" library, it synchronises data between the server and device. If you only want to save data in the server you should use a "client" library such as java-cloudant on github.

Comment: oh.. if i use client library then i want to also change code of add,update,delete query right?

Comment: Yeah, you will need to change the code to use the APIs that library provides.